# Unable to preview report - error occurred during report processing

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, sql-server-2012-datatools

I am getting the following error when trying to preview an RDL report.

[image]

1. I have full rights to the SQL SERVER
2. I have tested my connection to the datasource and it's fine
3. I have full rights to the reporting services (serverName/reports)
4. My datasource is set to windows authentication
5. The event viewer both on the local and remote machines shows nothing
6. SQL SERVER logs show nothing

Please note: this report is embedded within an on-premises CRM instance, but I need to update the report.

**What am I doing wrong? Any troubleshooting guidance would be most appreciated.**

Comment: Is your windows user set up as a user in CRM?

Comment: yes it is, why do you ask?

Comment: Sometimes we miss the easy things.

Comment: indeed! thank you for asking. yes, i'm able to get into CRM, i have read/write access, but not admin access.......but im not sure that i need any type of crm access?? arent they separate things?

Comment: Your windows user definitely needs to be set up as a CRM user with permission to read all of the data columns retrieved in your report (assuming you are using the filtered views).

Comment: thank you. i will upgrade to admin and see if that works, though im not sure if being an admin gives you permission to read everything?

Answer (score -1):

In that case run your report in new solution / another solution. Your issue will sort out.

I faced the same issue. Now sorted.